# wpf datagridcell element visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to change button visibility in celltemplate when mouse is over row in datagrid. For example when `MouseIsOver=True` visibility `True`,`MouseIsOver=False` visibility `False`. What should i use trigger? *                  *

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding .}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Button">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Visibility="Hidden">OK</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Data();
    }
}

public class Struct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public Data()
    {
        Items = new List<string>();
        Items.Add("First");
        Items.Add("Second");
        Items.Add("Third");
    }
}
}
```

- *

Answer (score 0):

If your button is hidden, it can't be hovered.

In Visual studio or Blend, change the style/Template of your button to have the ContentPresenter invisible :

Put a temporary button in your window, right click "Edit style"/"Edit a copy".
Name the style "InvisibleButtonStyle".

In the trigger section, add :

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
</Trigger>
```

Then destroy the temporary button, and apply the style to the DataGrid buttons :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource InvisibleButtonStyle}">OK</Button>
```

That's it , happy coding

Comment: @A191919, please tell if something 's wrong. I made a small demo I can send to you if needed. Regards